# Extended amenorrhea due to exercise - how to mitigate long-term damage?

Tags: exercise, body-fat, menstruation

One thing that female athletes with low body fat can encounter is amenorrhea. While not a problem in the short term, extended instances of this can lead to bone loss (osteopenia/osteoporosis). Are there over the counter ways to combat this, or does this require professional intervention to counteract?

Comment: It is something that someone experiencing this should see a physician for, as amenorrhea/infertility and osteopenia/porosis are not the only potential side effects - they are signs to alert you that you may need further evaluation.  Arrhythmias and other things are also possible.

Comment: @DoctorWhom - Expanded a trifle, I think that would make a great answer.